# How to generate array of tuples from a list in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a row as below (Int,List(String))

```
(22,List(B00000JCDS, B000004CSZ, B00016XN6Q, B00005LLY3, B00023B1UI))
```

I need to generate a tuple array or any other collection as below:

```
(22,B00000JCDS)
(22,B000004CSZ)
(22,B00016XN6Q)
(22,B00005LLY3)
(22,B00023B1UI)
```

How to generate this dataset in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> a._2.map((a._1,_))
res3: List[(Int, String)] = List((22,B00000JCDS), (22,B000004CSZ), (22,B00016XN6Q), (22,B00005LLY3), (22,B00023B1UI))
```

where a is `(22,List(B00000JCDS, B000004CSZ, B00016XN6Q, B00005LLY3, B00023B1UI))`

Answer (score 1):

The most readable thing which comes to mind is to use `for` comprehension:

```
scala>   val g = (22,List("B00000JCDS", "B000004CSZ", "B00016XN6Q", "B00005LLY3", "B00023B1UI"))
g: (Int, List[String]) = (22,List(B00000JCDS, B000004CSZ, B00016XN6Q, B00005LLY3, B00023B1UI))

scala>   
   |   for {
   |     fromList <- g._2
   |   } yield (g._1, fromList)

res3: List[(Int, String)] = List((22,B00000JCDS), (22,B000004CSZ), (22,B00016XN6Q), (22,B00005LLY3), (22,B00023B1UI))
```

If you want an array just call `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches to this for a given row `a`, as follows,

```
Array.fill(a._2.size)(a._1) zip a._2

(Iterator.continually(a._1) zip a._2.iterator) toArray

Array.tabulate(a._2.size)(i => (a._1, a._2(i)) )
```